# Copy selected query fields name in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench (SQL Editor). I need copy the list of columns in each query as was existed in Mysql Query Browser.
For example

```
Select * From tb
```

I want have the list of fields like as:
 id,title,keyno,......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you want to be able to get one or more columns for a specified table?

**1st way**
Do `SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table_name` and from there on depending on what you want have some basic filtering added by specifying you want only columns that data type is int, default value is null etc e.g. `SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table_name WHERE type='mediumint(8)' AND`null`='yes'`

**2nd way**
This way is a bit more flexible and powerful as you can combine many tables and other properties kept in MySQL's INFORMATION_SCHEMA internal db that has records of all db columns, tables etc. Using the query below as it is and setting TABLE_NAME to the table you want to find the columns for

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='your_table_name';
```

To limit the number of matched columns down to a specific database add `AND TABLE_SCHEMA='your_db_name'` at the end of the query

Also, to have the column names appear not in multiple rows but in a single row as a comma separated list you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,',')` instead of only `COLUMN_NAME`

Comment: yes. but my select query may be complex. for example `SELECT i.*,k.* FROM test i LEFT JOIN test2 k ON (k.id=i.id)`

Comment: If you only want to find the columns of any one, two, or more tables is there a purpose on joining the tables? You can still use the same query as in the answer and just add the second(or as many tables as you want) i.e. TABLE_NAME='test' OR TABLE_NAME='test2'. If that's not the case can you give a better example of what you are looking after?

Comment: I need have all fields name on right click as Mysql Query Browser. Because queries may be so complex.

Comment: The closest thing to what you want would be SHOW COLUMNS FROM (..your_query..) AS T, but it won't do the trick as the table needs to be fixed and not be dynamic/query based. The only 2 ways I can see to get one or more column names out of a table is by using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query or the SHOW COLUMNS version(edit) which is limited to one table only and you can set some basic criteria based on the field properties

Comment: Please do `SHOW COLUMNS FROM ...`  in mysql workbench (SQL Editor). you would have vertical results then copy of the list of columns would be impossible.

Comment: ehmm..sorry I don't think I understand what you want to do. Dedicate a bit more time to edit your question and explain what you need as well as provide a better example. I gave it the best I could but I can't take it any further than this, it doesn't make sense any more.

Comment: Thanks @George-T . I need any plugin that be able to copy row names of SQL EDITOR's query outputs. In old version of query browser by right clicking on query results, an option would be shown (Copy row datas with row names)

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` only takes one argument so `GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,',')`   did not work for me (it resulted in 2 commas per element)  but `GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', ')` did

Answer (score 1):

To select all columns in select statement, please go to SCHEMAS menu and right click ok table which you want to select column names, then select "Copy to Clipboard > Select All statement".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution accepted is fine, but it is limited to field names in tables. To handle arbitrary queries would be to standardize your select clause to be able to use regex to strip out only the column aliases. I format my select clause as "1 row per element" so 
`Select 1 + 1 as Col1, 1 + 2 Col2 From Table`
 becomes 
`Select 1 + 1 as Col1
, 1 + 2 Col2
From Table`

Then I use simple regex on the "1 row per select element"  version to replace `"^.* "` (excluding quotes) with nothing. The regex finds everything before the final space in the line, so it assumes your column aliases doesn't contain spaces (so replace spaces with underscore). Or if you don't like "1 row per element" then always use "as" keyword to give you a handle that regex can grasp.